# Exception thrown for changing Realm data outside of a transaction when the change was made inside a transaction

Tags: android, realm

The line that causes the exception is the closing bracket of the for loop:
*`failedHTTPRequests` is of type `RealmResults`

```
RealmSingleton.getUserInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    for (int i=0;i<failedHTTPRequests.size();i++){
                        if (failedHTTPRequests.get(i).getId().equals(FailedHTTPRequest.POST_USER_INFO))
                            failedHTTPRequests.get(i).deleteFromRealm();
//exception line    }

                }
            });
```

This seems like a pretty routine operation, except for the for loop. I'm aware that iterating through `RealmResults` can cause issues, and I'm going to change it, but I don't see how it can cause a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction`.

Any idea why this exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that I was trying to change data that belonged to a different realm. Shouldn't that throw a different exception?

Comment: Nope, the Realm the object is associated with is not in `write` state (not in a transaction), so it makes sense that it doesn't alter its error message just because _another_ Realm is in a write state